# Encrypting the Hadoop Distributed Cache file

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2, distributed-cache

As part of the Distributed Cache hadoop feature, hadoop copies files to the local filesystem on worker nodes. Is there a way to encrypt these local files?

Comment: I don't know if it is possible, but would encrypting them before adding them to cache and decrypting them after loading them from cache be an option?